# ListView fails to load data

Tags: android, android-listview

i'm really stuck with this and not able to move forward i'm trying to populate google calendar events into a listview and am not seeing any results. i'm sorry for posting such lengthy code but i'm really stuck!! 
My activity

```
public class EventListActivity extends Activity {

 private List<Events> events = new ArrayList<Events>();
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private ProgressDialog progressBar;
  private SelectableEventsAdapter eventsAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstance);
     getAccount();
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    setEventsListView();
}

private void setEventsListView() {
    Log.i("ReachedsetEvents", "Reached set Events view 1");
     final ListView eventsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_main);
     eventsAdapter = new SelectableEventsAdapter(this, events);
     //eventsAdapter.getView(0, eventsListView, eventsListView);
    eventsAdapter.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
    Log.i("ReachedsetEvents", "Reached set Events view 2");
    eventsAdapter.sort();

     private void retrieveEvents() {
    // Retrieves the attendees on a separate thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {

        EventsRetriever eventsRetriever =
            new EventsRetriever(EventListActivity.this, OAuthManager.getInstance()
                .getAccount());
        final List<Events> newevents = eventsRetriever.getEvents();
        Log.i("reachedRetrieve", "reached retrieve");
        // Update the progress bar
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

          public void run() {
            if (newevents != null) {
              events.clear();
              events.addAll(newevents);

             eventsAdapter.sort();
             eventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Got attendees, dismissing progress bar");
            if (progressBar != null) {
              progressBar.dismiss();
              Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Progress bar should have been dismissed");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }).start();
    // Show a progress bar while the attendees are retrieved from the phone's
    // database.
    progressBar =
        ProgressDialog.show(this, null, getString(R.string.retrieve_contacts_wait_text), true);
  }
           @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   // getAccount();
  }

  /**
   * Prompt user to choose an account and retrieve attendees from phone's
   * database.
   */
  private void getAccount() {
    OAuthManager.getInstance().doLogin(false, this, new OAuthManager.AuthHandler() {
      public void handleAuth(Account account, String authToken) {
        if (account != null) {
          retrieveEvents();
        }
      }
    });
  }}
```

my custom adapter

```
public SelectableEventsAdapter(Context context, List<Events> items) {
      super(context, R.layout.layout_main,items);
      inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   Events item = getItem(position);
    LinearLayout eventsView = getView(convertView);

    setViews(item, eventsView);
    return eventsView;
  }
  private LinearLayout getView(View convertView) {
      Log.i("Reached", "Reached getView long");
      LinearLayout eventsView;
    if (convertView == null) {
         eventsView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main,eventsView,true);

    } else {
        eventsView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
    return eventsView;
  }
  private void setViews(Events item, LinearLayout eventsView) {
        setTitleView(item, eventsView);

      }
     private void setTitleView(Events item, LinearLayout eventsView) {
   ListView titleView = (ListView) eventsView.findViewById(R.id.list_main);
       titleView.setEnabled(true);
    //titleView.setText(item.title);

}
```

and the retriever for getting the events:

```
  public EventsRetriever(Activity activity, Account account) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.account = account;
  }
  public static final String[] FIELDS = {
      CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
      CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
      CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,
      CalendarContract.Events.STATUS,
      CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
      CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,

      };


      public static final Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

      String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {CalendarServiceBuilder.ACCOUNT_NAME, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                CalendarServiceBuilder.ACCOUNT_NAME};


  /**
   * Get the list of user's contacts.
   * 
   * @return The list of contacts.
   */
  public List<Events> getEvents() {
    List<Events> result = new ArrayList<Events>();
    ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor =
        cr.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, FIELDS,null,null, null);

    try {
          if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
              String title =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                      CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
              String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                      CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION));
              String organizer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                      CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER));
              String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                      CalendarContract.Events.STATUS));
              String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                      CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION));
              result.add(new Events(title,description,organizer,status,location));
              Log.i("Reachedretriever", "Reached retriever");
             }

          }}
            finally {
                  cursor.close();
                }
        return result;

        }}
```

I am not able to see anything getting populated on the screen! Also just so that you know  i'm using unauthorised Oauth for the api access. 
The layout_main.xml contains just a ListView inside a linearlayout.
Please let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: At the point where you instantiate SelectableEventsAdapter, have you double checked to make sure that your events list is not empty?

Comment: Your code: final ListView eventsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_main);
eventsAdapter = new SelectableEventsAdapter(this, events);
eventsAdapter.setAdapter(eventsAdapter); Don't you need to set adapter for ListView?

Comment: @Olsavage yes you are right that was a mistake there... i set the adapter, there is a little improvement i just saw my progress bar for the first time but still i'm missing something... the listview is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the list of events in your adapter is not the same as the list in your activity.

So either call setAdapter() at last when the list of events is already populated, or create a setter in your adapter

```
setItems(List<Events> events){
     this.events = events
 }
```

and call it before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

You might also want to replace your threads/handler implementation with an AsyncTask which is much easier to read and faster to use (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks @NathanZ for pointing me in the right direction. I have got it up and running now.